# Error in Python when I do a specific request in the API

Tags: python, request

I'm getting an error in one specific python request. The API doc below:

```
data": [
        {
            "id": 999,
            "nome": "Nome Tarefa Teste",
            "codigo": "T01",
            "fase": {
                "id": 22,
                "nome": "Fase Teste",
                "codigo": "F01"
            },
            "descricaoHtml": "<p>Descrição Html</p>",
            "prioridade": 0,
            "situacao": 2,
            "dtCriacao": "2020-07-06T13:36:29Z",
            "dtInicio": "2020-07-06T03:00:00Z",
            "dtFim": "2020-07-23T03:00:00Z",
            "dtConclusao": "2020-07-23T03:00:00Z",
            "porcentagemConclusao": 0.00,
            "anexo": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "nome": "Slide1.png",
                    "url": "https://sults.com/Slide1.png",
                    "tamanho": 1545,
                    "dtCriacao": "2019-07-03T03:09:17Z"
                }
            ],
            "subTarefa": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "nome": "Primeira Subtarefa",
                    "dtCriacao": "2022-11-14T14:54:16Z",
                    "dtConcluido": null
                }
            ],
            ,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "size": 3,
    "totalPage": 1
}
```

My code:

```
for i in data['data']:
    nome.append(i['nome'])
    codigoTarefa.append(i['codigo'])
    situacaoTarefa.append(i['situacao'])
    faseNome.append(i['fase']['nome'])
    dtFimTarefa.append(i['dtFim'])
    dtInicioTarefa.append(i['dtInicio'])
    subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa']['nome'])
```

Everything works fine, except `subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa']['nome']`. I think its because at this part in the API documentation we have an ""["" before ""{""

Can anyone help me to get the info about `subTarefa > nome`
ps: `SubTarefa` is an `subTask`, and `nome` is the name of this `subTask` that is what I want.

Edit : with only `i['subTarefa']` I get this error :

```
File "C:\Users\Henrique Ferraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 215, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\Henrique Ferraz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 184, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert [] to Excel
```

because after this, I print the results in an Excel file.

Comment: Show the error. The full traceback, in your question, formatted as traceback.

Comment: Try `subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa'][0]['nome'])`.

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str 

But [subTarefas][nome] its Str in the doc

Comment: *in your question*: not in a comment. Comments can be removed.

Comment: i tried subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa'][0]['nome']) 

Error : IndexError: list index out of range 

The other lists works fine withou this last one

Comment: How many times do we have to say that you should put that in the question, not a comment? Click the "Edit" button.

Comment: Then you should do some basic debugging, and print out `i['subTarefa']` on the line before it, to see what its value is.

Comment: Maybe i need to pass anything before [subTarefas] 

I have a task, and subTarefas is an subTask 

Basically i want the name of the subtask

Comment: List index out of range will happen if `i['subTarefa']` is an empty list.

Comment: Your listed error doesn't originate in the code shown.

Comment: So `i['subTarefa']` is an empty list, which is in contrast to the data you've shown in the first block. It's hard to help when you show data that doesn't correspond to the error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to index `i['subTarefa']`. But you also have to confirm that it's not empty first.

Change:

```
subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa']['nome'])
```

to

```
if i['subTarefa']:
    subTarefa.append(i['subTarefa'][0]['nome'])
else:
    subTarefa.append('')
```

This will append an empty name if there's nothing in `subTarefa`.

Comment: Yessss resolved. Thanks

So the error occurred because they had an empty subtasks?

Comment: The original error happened because you left out the index. The second error happened because there was an empty subtask.